# Смещение вложенного списка <li>

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Вроде проверил все основные нюансы, посмотрел основные youtube уроки про комбинации селекторов, но все равно второй вложенный список (в третьем **LI** основного списка) все равно получается смещенным на основную таблицу.  Хотя первый размещается корректно

При этом я вижу то, что в снипете отображение идет корректо, а вот в локальном браузере нет..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
 *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.main-menu *{
  list-style: none;
}
.main-menu div ul{
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.main-menu a{
  color:red;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-menu li{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.main-menu ul ul{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  left:0;
}
.main-menu ul li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
      <title>MoreDoor</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/381ef55a42.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cuprum:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
     </head>
    
    <body>
    <header>
        <nav class="main-menu">
            <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"       ></i>Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-door-open"  ></i>Межкомнатные двери</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Первые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Вторые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Третьи</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Четвертые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Пятые</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-door-closed"></i>Входные Двери</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Шестые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Седьмые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Восьмые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Девятые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Десятые</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-paperclip"  ></i>Фурнитура</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-diagnoses   "></i>Услуги</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-highlighter"></i>Плинтусы</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>О компании</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-percentage"></i>Акции</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-atlas"></i>Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. У родительского li нужно было поставить `position:relative` (это было) и четкую высоту к примеру в 40px (этого не было).  После этого, у дочернего li нужно было поставить `position: absolute` (это было. требуется для ориентации относительно родителя) и смещение `top:40px` (этого не было) как раз в высоту родительского блока. И все будет ровно.

```css
 *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.main-menu *{
  list-style: none;
}
.main-menu div ul{
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.main-menu a{
  color:red;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-menu li{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  height:40px;

}
.main-menu ul ul{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  left:0;
  top: 40px;
}
.main-menu ul li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
      <title>MoreDoor</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/381ef55a42.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cuprum:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
     </head>
    
    <body>
    <header>
        <nav class="main-menu">
            <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"       ></i>Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-door-open"  ></i>Межкомнатные двери</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Первые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Вторые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Третьи</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Четвертые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Пятые</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-door-closed"></i>Входные Двери</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Шестые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Седьмые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Восьмые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Девятые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Десятые</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-paperclip"  ></i>Фурнитура</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-diagnoses   "></i>Услуги</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-highlighter"></i>Плинтусы</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>О компании</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-percentage"></i>Акции</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-atlas"></i>Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```